# Make link clickable when it's fully display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link on my website with telephone number. Four last digits in the number are hidden, so to see full number, you should click on it.

I want to make like when you click on number with hidden digits it shows the full number, and then you click on it to make a call (add attribute href="+0000000001111")

```js
jQuery('body').delegate('#phone-number[data-replace]', 'click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var older_value = jQuery(this).html();
  jQuery(this)
    .html(jQuery(this)
      .attr('data-replace'));
  $("#phone-number").attr("href=tel:+0000000001111");
});
```

```css
#phone-number {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Intro, impact;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: rgb(70, 70, 70) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden_number {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="phone-number" data-replace="+00 0000 0001111">+00 0000 000XXXX</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kerm131/5musfxb0/2/

Comment: So what's wrong? And to set attribute you must call it as `.attr('href', "VALUE")`

Comment: `.attr('href', 'tel:+0000000001111')` http://api.jquery.com/attr/.  Also `delegate` has been deprecated, you should use `.on` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a few changes to your code:

```js
jQuery('body').one('click', '#phone-number[data-replace]', function(event){  // use one instead of delegate as delegate has been deprecated and you only want to run this once
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = jQuery(this),
        older_value = $this.html(),
        number = $this.attr('data-replace');
    
    $this
      .html(number)                     // change number
      .attr('href', 'tel:' + number)    // change href
      .get(0).click();                  // fire click - optional, leave off if you want user to have to click again
});
```

```css
#phone-number {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Intro, impact;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: rgb(70, 70, 70) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden_number {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a id="phone-number" data-replace="+00 0000 0001111">+00 0000 000XXXX</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Works great!

Comment: could you give an advice how to change your solution if I have the same phone nubmer but in different places on page. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/kerm131/54d21hLp/

Comment: use a class instead of an id, although any reason why you are delegating the event? are these numbers dynamically added to the page or do they exist when the page is loaded?  You may need to bind the event directly http://jsfiddle.net/z1vd9mqj/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your jfiddle. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add `href` attribute-

`$( "#phone-number" ).attr( "href","tel:"+ jQuery(this).attr('data-replace'));`

Comment: Obviously this will be used inside function that is already there

Answer (score 0):

Consider update this line:
$( "#phone-number" ).attr( "href=tel:+0000000001111" );

To this

$( "#phone-number" ).attr( "href", "tel:+0000000001111" );

...and evenutally, try it from a MOBILE device. This function badly on desktop.